# ArrayList() imprime true al recorrerlo

Tags: java

tengo la siguiente función que me genera un `ArrayList` pero al momento de recorrerlo me devuelve true. como puedo ver el contenido

```
    public static ArrayList ordenaNodos(ArrayList nodeList){

    ArrayList cfdiList = new ArrayList();
    //recorre lista de nodos
    String cfdi = "";
    for(int i=0; i<nodeList.size(); i++){
       cfdi += nodeList.get(i).toString();
       if(nodeList.get(i).toString().equals("</cfdi:Comprobante>")){
           cfdiList.add(new ArrayList().add(cfdi));
           cfdi = "";
       }
    }

    return cfdiList;
}
```

Comment: El método ordenaNodos() retorna un ArrayList , deseas ver el contenido al recibir este valor?

Comment: Cómo lo recorres? Porque estás añadiendo un arraylist dentro de cada elemento

Comment: no. quiero ver el contenido del arreglo! pero cuando hago                                   for(int i =0; i<cfdis.size(); i++){
             System.out.println(cfdis.get(i));
        }       me retorna true

Comment: El resultado es un arraylist que tienes que recorrer con un bucle. Pero cada elemento es a su vez un arraylist lista de un elemento. Yo creo que te sobra un arraylist, solo necesitarías hacer un add, no dos

Comment: tienes razón, había una add de mas . gracias !

Comment: No hay de que, solucionado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeramente al agregar un elemento al `ArrayList`, estas agregando en realidad otro `ArrayList`, solo es necesario guardar el valor dentro del `ArrayList` `cfdiList` :

```
   //cfdiList.add(new ArrayList().add(cfdi));
    cfdiList.add(cfdi);
```

Para imprimir el resultado del método:

```
for(int i=0; i< resultadoOrdenaNodos.size(); i++){    
    System.out.println("Elemento" + i + " , valor: " +  resultadoOrdenaNodos.get(i));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Con esto debería retornar lo que deseas:

```
ArrayList cfdiList = new ArrayList(); 
String cfdi = "";
for(int i=0; i<nodeList.size(); i++){   //  Iteras la nodeList
    cfdi = nodeList.get(i).toString();  //  Obtienes el valor String del ojeto en el índice "i". No usar "+"
    //  Como ya tienes el valor en ese índice no vuelves a usar los metodos, simplemente comparas la variable "cfdi"
    if (cfdi.equals("</cfdi:Comprobante>")){
       cfdiList.add(cfdi);
    }
}
```

Espero te sirva, saludos.